# EF Interfaces - getting object by related type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, design-patterns, code-first, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to build a set of reusable EF models and interfaces. One such interface is called `ICategorised`, and looks as follows:

```
public interface ICategorised {
    int CategoryID { get; set; }
    Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

And here's what the Category object looks like:

```
public class Category {
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Type Type { get; set; } // Is 'Type' the wrong type for this?
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

I quite like the principle of this but I'm slightly stumped on how best to get and set the Type for any object which implements `ICategorised`. My end goal is the ability to create an object such as:

```
public class Car : ICategorised {
    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string CarName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

.. and somehow be able to query `Categories` where `Type==Car`.

Comment: How many types do you expect to occur?

Comment: Initially just a couple. My plan is to make this, the business logic, views, etc which I'm writing to go with it as easily reusable as possible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should reconsider the current usage of `ICategorized` as the Existential Type. It seems to me that actually this should be `Category`, because `Category` provides definitions for everything in `ICategorized` but doesn't actually implement it at present. If you want to keep `ICategorized` I would make `Category` implement it as a first point.

Secondly, I would make `Category abstract` because it shouldn't be instantiated directly. Then your `Car` and any other categorized class you create will derive directly from the `abstract Category`. This makes them `ICategorized` inherently too if you change your hierarchy as noted above.

That would achieve what you are after I think, and lead to a cleaner hierarchy that is extensible for future types. You can then query on `Type` directly as each specific `Category` subclass will have an explicit `Type` set, such as `Car`.

Hope that helps, or at least is a step in the right direction.

Comment: This is a much better approach. I dropped ICategorised and instead created an abstract Category class, with derived classes for each type which is categorised.